# Kotlin using anonymous inner class before declaration

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm migrating one of my android projects to kotlin, and in java I frequently declare anonymous inner classes at the bottom of a class, for example

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle ...) {

    ...

    findViewById(R.id.btnDelete).setOnClickListener(mDeleteClickListener);
}


...
...
...


private View.OnClickListener mDeleteClickListener = new View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Process event using class variables
        findViewById(...)
    }
};
```

However consider this similar pattern in kotlin:

```
override fun onCreate(b: Bundle) {

    ...

    findViewById<View>(R.id.btnDelete).setOnClickListener(mDeleteClickListener)
}

...
...
...

private val mDeleteClickListener = object : View.OnClickListener {

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        // Process event using class variables
        findViewById(...)
    }
}
```

It doesn't allow me to do so, since it the function `onCreate` is declared before the inner class. I would have to move it above the functions where I use it, and I don't like to declare these inner classes at the top of the class.

Is there a way to use this pattern in kotlin?

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting? The same code works here.

Comment: Are you sure that's the reason? Could you show the error you get? Try replacing `override fun onCreate(b: Bundle)` with `override fun onCreate(b: Bundle?)`

Comment: Ah I see. It was actually in a constructor `init` block where this was happening, not `onCreate`. It does work in functions, my mistake. Will edit question